# Problem Exporting Rig/Character to UE4

Tags: rigging, export, unreal-engine

When exporting my Rig/Character to fbx. I'll import it to UE4 and everything works but the feet. For some reason, each foot is disconnected and are created as their own Rig/Character in UE4. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong in blender and forgot something or if this is a UE4 problem.
[image]

Project File: http://www.filedropper.com/ue4charactertest3_2

Forgot to add that there is a error that comes along with the import to UE4.
"Could not find the bind pose. It will use time 0 as bind pose."

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you export the mesh with rig rather that exporting them separately. Also in general make sure you've applies your rotation and scale etc and make sure mesh to rig parenting has been set up properly.

Comment: I've checked all of that and I also export the rig and character mesh together. Everything seems right. Hence why I'm so confused why it's not working.